# Ajustar imagem dentro de botão

Tags: android, button

Alguém sabe como ajusto a imagem ao tamanho do botão sem que ela fique cortada?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Button:

```
  <Button
    android:id="@+id/funcionario"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
    android:text="| Ver Funcionários"
    android:background="@drawable/botoes"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/funcionario"
    android:drawableTint="#ffff"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

Usar o atributo `padding` deve resolver o seu problema.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/funcionario"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="| Ver Funcionários"
    android:background="@drawable/botoes"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/funcionario"
    android:drawableTint="#ffff"/>
```

Esse link pode te ajudar a entender como o `padding` funciona e como ele é diferente do `margin`
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619899/difference-between-a-views-padding-and-margin/4619934

Comment: Não funcionou, ele continua grande d+, e se eu colocar um height tipo 50 dp, a imagem fica cortada

Comment: Já tentou usar um layout, LinearLayout por exemplo, ao invés de um botão?

Comment: O button está dentro d um linear

Comment: Entao, nao usa Button e sim algum layout que te permita melhor controle das views que estao dentro.